# Show hand in a HEADs UP situation to the raiser while playing MTT

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy, etiquette, mtt

playing a MTT:

UTG goes ALLIN (35-40BB, it covers me). The action fold to me on the big blind. Can I show my cards to the raiser to get more information?

Just want to know if I CAN do that or not.

Comment: Home games maybe, but any casino no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TDA rules](https://www.pokertda.com/view-poker-tda-rules/), the probably most common end established rules followed in MTTs, state the following:

> 68:  Exposing Cards and Proper Folding
>
> Exposing cards with action pending, including the current player when
>   last to act, may result in a penalty but not a dead hand. Any penalty
>   begins at the end of the hand.

That being said, house rules vary and can be drastically different. Ask to see the house rules or ask the floor-person. Pointing to the TDA rules is pointless if the house is not officially following them.

Some house rules will declare that your hand is automatically killed when you expose your cards before stating your action, so make sure you know which rules are being followed.